# How to create a polymer component library?

Tags: polymer, components

I can see how when you generate a new component that you also get some great documentation for the element.  It includes detail about the properties and shows a code example of how to use the element.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to create a way for component library to find all my components and to show them in one place instead of just having individual pages that show each individual element.

Is that possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

[webcomponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/) provide collections.

This is propably what you are looking for. Acording to manual

> Creating a collection is easy. Simply create an empty GitHub repository with bower dependencies to all the elements or collections you want to include.

https://www.webcomponents.org/publish-collection

Comment: This seems to be a great solution for when we want to publish our components to the world so that we can encourage reuse.  And I'm sure we'll get there.

But what I'm asking about is how to create a local styleguide / component library that we can host a collection of documentation for components.